# how to grep several lines after a certain line

Tags: grep

I have several files that goes like that:

```
abcd

several lines

abcd

several lines

abcd

several lines

.
.
.
```

what I want to do (preferably using grep) is to get the 20 lines immediately following the LAST abcd line.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
awk '/abcd/ {n=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=n;i<=n+20;i++) print a[i]}' file
```

It will search for pattern `abcd` and update `n` so only last will be stored.
It also store all line in array `a`
Then it print `20` lines form last pattern found in the `END` section.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-A` option:

```
-A NUM, --after-context=NUM
      Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line
      containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.  
      With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning
      is given.
```

So:

```
$ grep -A 20 abcd file.txt
```

will give you `abcd` lines + 20 lines after each. To get that last 21 lines, use `tail`:

```
$ grep -A 20 abcd file.txt | tail -21
```